# How to circumvent the maximum number of bind values for Sybase ASE and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sap-ase, jooq, bind-variables

I'm running [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) integration tests for large conditions of the form

```sql
WHERE x IN (:1, :2, :3, :4, ..., :3001, :3002)
```

The above example depicts that there are many bind variables in an `IN` condition. Oracle has a well-known limitation of 1000 values (bind values or inline values) between the parentheses of an IN condition. The solution is simple, just write:

```
WHERE x IN (:1, :2, :3, :4, ..., :1000) OR x IN (:1001, ...)
```

Sybase ASE 15.5 and SQL Server 2008 R8 on the other hand seem to have an overall limitation on the number of bind values: 2000 for Sybase ASE and 2100 for SQL Server respectively. In other words, there seems to be no way to split / transform the above condition using bind values for these two databases. Is there any way to circumvent that problem, short of inlining all bind values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way we've finally implemented this in [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) is by using a `ControlFlowException` to abort rendering of SQL with bind values once we've encountered any limit. The limits are:

- SQLite: 999
- Ingres 10.1.0: 1024
- Sybase ASE 15.5: 2000
- SQL Server 2008: 2100

We've also blogged about this here:

- http://blog.jooq.org/2013/04/28/rare-uses-of-a-controlflowexception

Once this limit is hit, the `ControlFlowException` is caught at the query rendering site, where it is simply re-rendered with all bind values inlined - which always works (until you hit the query size limit, if any, of course).

We're assuming that inlined bind values, and the repetitive hard-parses that incur are OK in these cases, as chances that an execution plan can really be reused with such highly dynamic SQL are slim.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a table type, and then say `IN (SELECT column FROM @variableThatIsMyTableType)` then you aren't limited at all.

I won't regurgitate MSDN - which covers [table types and table valued parameters here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

The SQL you then generate looks something like:

```
DECLARE @variableThatIsMyTableType mySchema.myTableType
INSERT @variableThatIsMyTableType VALUES (1)
INSERT @variableThatIsMyTableType VALUES (2)
EXEC proc @variableThatIsMyTableType
```

However, when submitting this from C# and SqlClient, it creates what's called a 'trivial plan' - and you can read about TVPs and trivial plans [here](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/The-interesting-case-of-TVPs-and-plan-compilation.aspx) and [here](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/TVPs-and-plan-compilation-the-reprise.aspx). Doing it via SQL direct would result in a cached plan, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: That certainly looks like a viable way to circumvent the problem. On the other hand, I have full control over the SQL rendered by jOOQ, so in this case, inlining all bind variables would be simpler than creating ad-hoc table types.

Comment: Yeah, it certainly seems like a 'six of one and half a dozen of the other' situation.